# Why is it not possible to update xcode from 4.2 to 4.3?

Tags: xcode

Both versions were released as downloads from the Mac App Store, so why xcode 4.2 is not upgradable?

Comment: how is this related to programming?

Comment: @Yossarian: It's about a software tool commonly used by programmers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 4.2 download was just an installer, but the 4.3 download is a self-contained package that will be updatable directly from the Mac App Store.

Comment: Thank you. Answer will be accepted in 11 minutes, according to SE.

Comment: @Phil it won't accept the answer automatically, it's telling you that you will be allowed to mark this as correct in 11 minutes.